# What is the purpose of mixed constructors?

Tags: java

What is the purpose of doing something like:

```
Employee a = new OverTimeEmployee();
```

or

```
OverTimeEmployee a = new Employee();
```

Where OverTimeEmployee is a subclass of employee?

and what is the proper name for it? I am guessing mixed constructor is not right

Comment: thank you all for the helpful and quick responses!

Comment: `OverTimeEmployee a = new Employee();` "Where OverTimeEmployee is a subclass of employee?" - That won't compile.

Comment: @Michael, that is what i stated in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called object inheritance.

It is one of the main things of Object Oriented Programming, along with [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) .

So in the code:

```
class Employee {
   ...
}

class OverTimeEmployee extends Employee {
   ...
}
```

So the reason you can do this:

```
Employee a = new OverTimeEmployee();
```

is because `OverTimeEmployee` is a type of `Employee`.

I do not believe you can do what you did in the second example because not all `Employee`'s are `OverTimeEmployee` and you will get an **error**.

Comment: Hm, maybe polymorphism (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) should be mentioned here as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
Employee a = new OverTimeEmployee();
```

is called 'Polymorphism'.

Polymorphism: "One name, Multiple forms".

Polymorphism is the capability of an action or method to do different things based on the object that it is acting upon.

This can be done when OverTimeEmployee is a subclass of Employee, i.e. `OverTimeEmployee extends Employee`. So basically, you can use it only when there is also Inheritance in picture. Polymorphism is used with method overloading.

Reason: In case of Polymorphism, actual object type and not the reference type is used to determine which version of the method to call. Methods are bound at compile time (as opposed to runtime in case of overriding).

Suppose you have a method called `printDescription()` in both `OverTimeEmployee` and say `RegularEmployee` (one more subclass of Employee).
In the OverTimeEmployee class's method say you are printing `int overtimerate` and in `RegularEmployee` say you are printing `String perks`.

```
class OverTimeEmployee {
  int overtimerate;
  .
  .
  .

  void printDescription() {
     System.out.println("I am overtime employee with pay rate " + overtimerate);
  }
}

class RegularEmployee {
      String perks;
      .
      .
      .

      void printDescription() {
         System.out.println("I am regular employee with perks " + perks);
   }
}
```

Then you do this:

```
OverTimeEmployee ot = new Employee(20); // initializing orvertimerate as 20

RegularEmployee rt = new Employee("Free parking"); // initializing perks as "Free parking"
```

`ot.printDescription()` will print

```
I am overtime employee with pay rate 20
```

`rt.printDescription()` will print

```
I am regular employee with perks Free parking
```

Also note that, `OverTimeEmployee a = new Employee();` won't complie since OverTimeEmployee  is subclass of Employee.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If `OverTimeEmployee` is a subclass of `Employee`, then you can't do `OverTimeEmployee a = new Employee();`.  That won't compile.

`Employee a = new OverTimeEmployee();` gets to the heart of object-oriented programming and inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used for polymorphism where the run time reference to the object will determine which method gets called. So if both Employee and OverTimeEmployee have  a earnings method depending and the during execution of the program Employee contains a reference to OverTimeEmployee then the OverTimeEmployee's earnings method would be invoked.